# Characteristic and order of a field

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with characteristic $p$, prime.

Then $1$ has order $p$ in $(\mathbb{F}, +)$. I don't understand why this then implies that $p$ divides the order of $\mathbb{F}$?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from [Lagrange's theorem on groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) (of which, $(\mathbb{F},+)$ is one).

Namely, the subgroup generated by $1$, $\langle 1 \rangle$, has order $p = \text{char}(\mathbb{F})$. Hence, it must divide the order of $\mathbb{F}$ overall.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.